# Samsung Smart TV App (not Tizen) audio plays only once

Tags: audio, html5-audio, samsung-smart-tv

In a Samsung Smart TV App up to 2014 (not Tizen) I have tried two ways to play a short (about a second) audio file and tested it in the 2014 emulator 5.1:

index.html:

```
<!-- HTML5 audio tag -->
<audio id="audio" src="http://luniks.net/other/0-99A-Z/1.ogg"></audio>

<!-- Player plugin -->
<object id="pluginPlayer" classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER"></object>
```

Main.js:

```
Main.keyDown = function() {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    // arrow left on remote control, just for testing
    if (keyCode == 4) {
        // HTML5 audio tag
        document.getElementById("audio").play();
    }
    // arrow right on remote control, just for testing
    if (keyCode == 5) {
        // Player plugin            
        var playerObj = document.getElementById('pluginPlayer');
        playerObj.Play("http://luniks.net/other/0-99A-Z/1.ogg");
    }
};
```

Each way, the audio file is played only once during the app's lifecycle and only plays again when restarting the app.
I am not sure if the sound is muted or if audio doesn't play at all after it played once.

The same with a `<video>` tag works fine, the video can be repeatedly played without problems.

When a `<video>` tag is present (defined after the `<audio>` tag), the `<audio>` tag does nothing.
When playing audio with the Player plugin while the video is playing, the video continues to play but is muted.

My final goal is to play a series of short audio files while a video that possibly has (low volume) sound is playing. From my experience so far, I can forget about that. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Just add loop="true" in the audio tag and test. It works fine for me.

Comment: It is maybe not clear from my question, but I don't want to loop an audio file but play a series of different short audio files.